How can I retrieve the components from a managed package version that I own?
Scenario: I have a developer org where i've assigned a namespace and created a 1st generation managed package, and uploaded a couple released package versions to it, the last one being more than 1 year ago. After that I've developed several bugfixes, added some features to it and so on, and now I'm about to upload a new released package version.
Problem: I need to create a release notes document, but I lost track of all the changes I made between that last released version till now. Also, I'm not using any sort of source revision control system, git or similar.
Question: I'd like to compare all the components (apex, flows, etc.) between that last released package version and the current ones in the org, to spot the differences. Given that I'm the owner of the org/code/package and all (not a subscriber), is there a way I can retrieve the contents of that specific package version? (so i can later compare it locally)
Thank you!

In case if package passed security review -- it might be possible to create patch org for the last released version,  and then you could retrieve the state of metadata of that particular released version

Thank you @kurunve! The patch org approach worked perfectly for my case.

As suggested by kurunve in the comments above, we can create a pach org from a specific released version, and then retrieve the metadata from that org, as long as we have the patch org option enabled, that seems to be tied to the securit review process.
